# Minimum number of rectangles needed to cover all the rectangles?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

We are given m number of rectangles on the coordinate plane. We need to cover all the rectangles using only one fixed size rectangle. We need to provide the minimum number of rectangles needed to cover all the rectangles. Fixed size rectangle can be used as many times as you wanted but we need to minimize the count.

Comment: ... Wouldn't you pick the largest rectangle?

Comment: We are given one fixed size rectangle how many such rectangles needed to cover all the rectangle is needed to provide.